# Don't save info in table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to save the information to the database in the following way:

```
def insert_into_db_before_eat(table, id_row, time, sugar, actra_ui, xe):
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({id_row},{time},{sugar},{actra_ui},{xe})")
    con.commit()
```

But I get the following error:

```
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({int(id_row)},{time},{sugar},{actra_ui},{xe})")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "17": syntax error
```

Using next data:

```
('Sugar_before_eat_after_sleep', 17, 2021-10-24 17:01:21, 1, 10, 5)
```

UPD:
Check for data and types, get next

```
'Sugar_before_eat_after_sleep', 17, 2021-10-24 17:39:33, 10, 5, 2
<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>
```

UPD2:
If I use next code, it's work:

```
def insert_into_db_before_eat(id_row, time, sugar, actra_ui, xe):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sugar_before_eat_after_sleep VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (id_row, time, sugar, actra_ui, xe))
    con.commit()
```

But I want to change table

Comment: What is `2021-10-24 17:01:21` supposed to be? A string?

Comment: It's datetime.fromtimestamp(date)

Comment: the function takes six parameters but you only pass five?

Comment: My mistake in the question, fixed

Comment: What is the evaluated values of `f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({int(id_row)},{time},{sugar},{actra_ui},{xe})"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, it works:

```
insert_into_db_before_eatt(id_row, time, sugar, actra_ui, xe):
    table = 'Sugar_before_eat_after_sleep'
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"% table,
                (id_row, time, sugar, actra_ui, xe))
    con.commit()
```